# How to change setting in git repo initiated with --bare

Tags: git

I have set up a repo to handle a live website. On the remote server, I did:

```
git init --bare
cat > hooks/post-receive
#! /bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/dev git checkout -f
```

So, this configured so that I can push my local repo to the www/dev folder. Now I want to push these changes to the live site. I've changed the path on the GIT_WORK_TREE setting in the hooks/post-receive file to the new folder, but this isn't actioned when I push to this repo - it still updates the folder on the original path.

How can I get the repo to see the new configuration?

Comment: You could manually (using e.g. `vim`) the file hooks/post-receive and make sure that the path is correct and pointing to the new folder

Comment: That's what I've done (I'll update the post to make it clearer), but it seems not to be recognising it.

Comment: That implies that the post-receive hook is not being run, probably due to not setting it as executable.  If you manually ran it once with `sh hooks/post-receive`, for instance, it would *look* ready, but not actually *be* ready.

Comment: Thanks, I ran `chmod +x hooks/postreceive` and it's now updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check that post-receive hook is executable and directory in GIT_WORK_TREE is writable to the user performing git push.

Add

```
echo 'In post receive hook'
```

to hook script to see if hook is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. `hooks/post-receive` was not executable, so I ran `chmod +x hooks/post-receive` and it now works fine.